# Handle gateway timeout in Microsoft Bot framework (node.js)

Tags: node.js, azure, timeout, botframework

I am working on the Chatbot project using node.js which is deploy on azure platform and integrate with facebook messenger. Currently, I'm facing an performance issue whereby after timeout the bot seems to take longer period of time to respond to user.

Please advise.

[image]

I have found possible one solution online (https://blog.botframework.com/2017/11/02/optimizing-latency-bot-framework/). However, I was returned "null" after 30 minutes on the console log.

Here's the code:

```
let chatConnector = ...;
... 
setInterval(() => {
    chatConnector.getAccessToken((error) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }, (token) => {
            console.log(`token refreshed: ${token}`); 
        });
}, 30 * 60 * 1000 /* 30 minutes in milliseconds*/ );
```

Comment: If your bot application is hosted on Azure Web Apps, there is a timeout limitation for requests against to Azure Web Apps (in 230 sec). You should avoid long time progress in bot application.

Comment: Are you asking for a solution as to avoid your bot timing out? What is your bot trying to do when it times out? Is it performing long API calls to external services?